# How to wait for a function in the doBackground to return in android?

Tags: java, android, wait

I have a asyc task that stores objects in cloudmine. Now I want to wait for the confirmation from cloudmine that the objects are stored. But before I get the conversation the postExecute method starts, which gives the wrong toast message. Main problem is that the cloudmine task itself is async and so I want doInBacground to wait for the cloudmine async to finish. Nothing I have tried has worked.

Here is the code:

```
public class createCloudmineLot extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,Boolean>
{
    private boolean success;
    private boolean inputFault;
    protected void onPostExecute(Boolean arg0)
    {
        System.out.println("postExecute sucess value: " + success);
        if(inputFault)
            {
                t = Toast.makeText(AddParking.this, "No Input!Please press enter after each input",Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                t.show();
            }
        else
            if(arg0)
                {
                t = Toast.makeText(AddParking.this, "Parking Lot was added:" + success,Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                t.show();
                }
            else
                {
                t = Toast.makeText(AddParking.this, "Unable to add Parking Lot" + success,Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                t.show();
                }
        return;         
    }
    @Override
    protected Boolean doInBackground(Void... params)
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
         CMApiCredentials.initialize(APP_ID, API_KEY, getApplicationContext());//initializing Cloudmine connetion
         SimpleCMObject parkingLot = new SimpleCMObject();
         if(name.equals("") | address.equals("") | pricing.equals("") | hours.equals("") | latitude.equals("") | longitude.equals(""))
             {
             inputFault = true;
             return null;
             }
         parkingLot.add("name", name);
         parkingLot.add("address",address);
         parkingLot.add("pricing",pricing);
         parkingLot.add("hours",hours);
         double lat = Double.parseDouble(latitude);
         double lon = Double.parseDouble(longitude);
         CMGeoPoint locationCoordinates = new CMGeoPoint(lat,lon);
         parkingLot.add("location",locationCoordinates);
         parkingLot.save(new ObjectModificationResponseCallback() 
         {
                public void onCompletion(ObjectModificationResponse response) 
                {
                        success = response.wasSuccess();
                        System.out.println("doInbackground: "+ success);

                }
        });

        return success;
    }//end of doBackground

}//end on AsyncTask
```

This is when I try with Broadcast Receivers. Using the receiver, nothing happens.

```
public class EditParking extends Activity
{
private ListView lotList;
private ArrayList<String> lots;
private ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdpt;

private class ReceiveBroadcastActivity extends BroadcastReceiver 
{

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) 
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        System.out.println("received");
        ArrayList<String> lots = intent.getStringArrayListExtra("ParkingLots");
        ListView lotlist = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.lotList);
        ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdpt = new ArrayAdapter<String>(EditParking.this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,lots);
        lotList.setAdapter(arrayAdpt);

        System.out.println("lots: "+ lots);
    }


};


public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.editparking_layout);
    lotList = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.lotList);
    lots = new ArrayList<String>(); 
    lots.add("hello");
    arrayAdpt = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,lots);
    lotList.setAdapter(arrayAdpt);
    arrayAdpt.setNotifyOnChange(true);


    CMApiCredentials.initialize(APP_ID, API_KEY, getApplicationContext());//initializing Cloudmine connection
    CMStore store = CMStore.getStore();
    store.loadAllApplicationObjects(new CMObjectResponseCallback() 
    {
        public void onCompletion(CMObjectResponse response) 
        {
            for(CMObject object : response.getObjects()) 
            {
            // do something with each object
                SimpleCMObject lot = (SimpleCMObject)object;
                String lotInfo = lot.getString("name") + "\n" + lot.getString("address") + 
                        "\nPrice: " + lot.getString("pricing") + "\nHours: " + lot.getString("hours");
                System.out.println(lotInfo);

            }
            Intent broadcastIntent = new Intent();
            lots.add("world");
            broadcastIntent.putStringArrayListExtra("ParkingLots", lots);
            broadcastIntent.setAction("com.cs275.findparking.broadcast");
            sendBroadcast(broadcastIntent); 
        }
```

Comment: Which toast message it show.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the call you are doing inside the doInBackground is also an asynchronous call, you need to realize that by the time the execution thread reaches the end of doInBackground and returns an object, the onPostExecute will be called, so basically the problem in your case is that since your call is also asynchronous, its not blocking the thread and it moves inmediately to the end of the doInBackground method and the "callback" you receive from that call is executed way later than the whole asynctask did it's job, so, that said there's different ways to approach the issue.

1.- You could force the worker thread in doInBackground to wait for your callback to be executed(this requires a perfect understanding of java threads and the wait/notify methods)

2.- A simple approach would be, not to rely on onPostExecute method, and in stead send a Broadcast Receiver message from the callback method of your call, which will be handled in your activity whenever is done..

Regards!

Comment: I do know about threads and processes from system programming, but that was in C. In this case, is asyc task another process or a thread. Because then I don't understand where to call wait or join.

Comment: The method doInBackground runs in a separate thread you need to stop it before it calls return and let it go after your callback is executed or just go for the second option is simpler

Comment: if going with the broadcast receiver option, when should I send the broadcast, like within the onCompletion(ObjectModificationResponse response) or just inside the do background

Comment: hey do you mind looking at my code using the broadcast, i posted it in the question. The receiver is not responding mainly because I think I am send the broadcast incorrectly.